# set segmented control with pageview

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a UIView and I added a segmented control to this view and created UIPageView programmatically. Then I added two UIViewController s to this page view with an array. Now I can move to the page well but I need to change the selected segment control with my move.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `selectedSegmentIndex` property of segmented control after pageView did navigate to some page